# Adding a correctly sized rectangle behind text

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am currently appending text nodes to an SVG as follows:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(...);
node.append("text")
    .attr("dy", 10)
    .attr("dx", 4)
    .text(function (d) { return d["name"]; });
```

There are currently about 10 nodes, each with a name.

I want to add a rectangle below each of the text nodes, using the correct width, I have tried this:

```
node.select<SVGTSpanElement>("text")
    .each(function(x, i) {
        console.log(this.getComputedTextLength());
        node.append("rect")
            .attr("fill", "#cccccc05")
            .attr("width", this.getComputedTextLength())
            .attr("height", 20)
    });
```

My problem is that (kind of obviously) I am creating 10 rectangles **per** node, not one for each node.

How do I include the calculation for text width, and add a single rectangle per text element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without refactoring your code too much, simply change *where* you're appending the rectangles. In this case, the parent node of the texts themselves:

```
node.select<SVGTSpanElement>("text")
    .each(function(x, i) {
        console.log(this.getComputedTextLength());
        d3.select(this.parentNode).append("rect")
            .attr("fill", "#cccccc05")
            .attr("width", this.getComputedTextLength())
            .attr("height", 20)
    });
```

However, the most idiomatic way is using `each()` for the `node` selection, not for the selection of texts inside it. Then, you get the text length for each `node` element, something like this:

```
node.each(function(x, i) {
    d3.select(this).append("rect")
        .attr("fill", "#cccccc05")
        .attr("width", d3.select(this).select("text").node().getComputedTextLength())
        .attr("height", 20)
    });
```